# Recursive Linked List Reversal Hangs with Print Statements

Tags: python, recursion, linked-list

I'm working on a Python program that reverses a linked list using recursion. I've implemented the reversal function and added print statements to help me understand the process. However, when I include certain print statements, the program hangs and doesn't complete. The reversal seems to work fine without those print statements.

```py
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next

    def __repr__(self):
        next = self.next
        val = self.val
        out = f"ListNode({val}, "
        count_paren = 1
        while next is not None:
            val = next.val
            out += f"ListNode({val}, "
            next = next.next
            count_paren += 1
        out += f"{next}"
        out += count_paren * ")"
        return out

def reverse(head):
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head
    print("1 HEAD", head)
    new_head = reverse(head.next)
    print("2 NEW_HEAD", new_head)
    head.next.next = head
    print("3 HEAD", head)
    print("4 NEW_HEAD", new_head)
    head.next = None
    print("5 HEAD", head)
    print("6 NEW_HEAD", new_head)
    return new_head

lst = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(4, ListNode(5)))))
print(lst)
print(reverse(lst))
```

Without the print statements:

```
    print("3 HEAD", head)
    print("4 NEW_HEAD", new_head)
```

the reversal works fine. However, if I uncomment those lines, the program hangs.

I would appreciate any insights into why this is happening and how I can modify the print statements to understand the process better without causing the hang. I am using python version of `3.11.2`.

Comment: Because after `head.next.next = head`, you have created a loop in your list which you only break after these two print lines, when you do `head.next = None`

Comment: You have an infinite loop in your \_\_repr__ implementation

Comment: This isn't a good fit for recursion in the first place. If your list has more than 1000 elements, the program will crash, even if you implement it correctly. Only use recursion for logaithmic traversals, like balanced trees and divide & conquer algorithms like merge sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting `head.next.next = head` and then calling `__repr__` with `print("3 HEAD", head)` or `print("4 NEW_HEAD", new_head)`. In `__repr__`the loop iteratively finds the `.next` attribute, but this causes an infinite loop as after two iterations the node being processed is `head.next.next`, which you have set to be `head` itself! The value of `next` in the loop goes:

`head` -> `head.next` -> `head.next.next` (=`head`) -> `head.next` -> `head.next.next` (=`head`)

As you can see this causes a loop, so removing the print statements fixes the problem.

You can actually prevent a loop being formed entirely by 'breaking the chain' of `.next` earlier in the function. One way to do this is to get a reference to `head.next` at the start of the function, then we can safely set `head.next = None` and not risk causing a infinite loop; if you run this function you will see we can safely call `__repr__` anywhere:

```
def reverse(head):
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head
    print(f"1 {head = }")
    head_next = head.next
    print(f"2 {head = }")
    head.next = None
    print(f"3 {head = }")
    new_head = reverse(head_next)
    print(f"4 {head = }\n{new_head = }")
    head_next.next = head
    print(f"5 {head = }\n{new_head = }")
    return new_head
```

Also, you can simplify your `__repr__` function by making it recursive:

```
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"ListNode({self.val}, {self.next})"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have `print` statements *during* the reversal process. That reversal will temporarily create cycles, and if in that state you call `print`, which calls `__repr__`, you'll get into an infinite loop.

The solution is to not call `print` with a *node* as argument while you reverse your list (as you already discovered), at least not when the list temporarily has a cycle.

That temporary cycle is created when you do `head.next.next = head`, and is broken again when you do `head.next = None`. It might be a good idea to perform a tuple assignment, so that there is no more moment (in your Python code) where the list has this cycle:

```
head.next.next, head.next = head, None
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be in the way you are printing your statements with the use of your "**repr**" function, the method of the ListNode class is recursively calling it self, causing it to be infinite recursion hence, the hanging

try the below given code:

```
def __repr__(self, visited=None):
if visited is None:
    visited = set()
if self in visited:
    return "ListNode(...)"
visited.add(self)
next_node = self.next
val = self.val
out = f"ListNode({val}, "
if next_node is not None:
    out += next_node.__repr__(visited)
out += ")"
return out
```

Answer (score 0):

When the reverse function is called recursively,
it must correctly update the references to the next node before the recursive call is executed.
In the source code, after a recursive call to the reverse function,
the reference to the next node is not updated before the next recursive step
is performed.
This causes an infinite loop to occur when printing nodes in the while loop due to incorrect links to the following nodes.

**I would do this:**

```py
def reverse(head):
    if not head or not head.next:
        return head

    def reverse_helper(current, prev=None, steps=[]):
        """"""
        if current is None:
            print("The condition for exiting recursion has been reached.")
            return prev, steps
        else:
            print(f"1 HEAD {current}")

        next_node = current.next
        current.next = prev
        steps.append(f"{len(steps) + 2} NEW_HEAD {current}")
        return reverse_helper(next_node, current, steps)

    new_head, reverse_steps = reverse_helper(head)
    for step in reverse_steps:
        print(step)
    return new_head
```

**Good luck!**